# Passing Values from a CSV file into an Ansible playbook

Tags: csv, ansible, checkpoint

The files below are my playbook, inventory, and a CSV file ( my dictionary)

**network_objects.yml**

```
---
- hosts: all
  connection: httpapi
  gather_facts: False
  vars_files:
    - 'my_var.yml'

  tasks:
  - name: add-host
    check_point.mgmt.cp_mgmt_host:
      name: New Host 1
      ip_address: 192.0.2.1
      state: present
      auto_publish_session: yes

  - name: add-group
    check_point.mgmt.cp_mgmt_group:
      name: New Group 1
      members:
        - New Host 1
      state: present
      auto_publish_session: yes
```

**my_var.yml**

```
ansible_httpapi_validate_certs: False
ansible_httpapi_use_ssl: True
ansible_network_os: check_point.mgmt.checkpoint
ansible_python_interpreter: "python3"
ansible_user: admin
ansible_password: password
```

**hosts**

```
[check_point]
checkpoint ansible_host=#IP address of checkpoint
```

**users.csv**

```
Name,IP Address,Comments
PCUSER1,10.11.92.44, Created by User Feb 19 2021
PCUSER2,10.11.12.13, Created by User 02/19/2012
```

**readCSV.yml**           ---> This  reads a csv file called users.csv

```
- name: "Check for CSV File"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Read CSV File and Return a dictionary
    read_csv:
      path: users.csv
      key: name
    register: user

  - ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: '{{ user }}
```

What I want to achieve,

I want to be able to read my CSV and pass those variables in the order the CSV data are listed. Then I can publish the New Host ( with all the Names, IP Addresses, Comments ) to Checkpoint

```
  - name: add-host
    check_point.mgmt.cp_mgmt_host:
      name: {{ Get all Names  from CSV File }}
      ip_address: {{ Get all IP Addresses from CSV File }}
      comments: {{ Get all Comments from CSV File }}
```

Comment: for the loop, use

loop: "{{ user.dict |dict2items }} "

```
 - name: add-host
    check_point.mgmt.cp_mgmt_host:
      name: {{ item.value.Name }}
      ip_address: {{ item.value.IP} 
      comments: {{ item.value.Comments}}
   loop: "{{ user |dict2items}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 - name: add-host
    check_point.mgmt.cp_mgmt_host:
      name: {{ item.key }}
      ip_address: {{ item.value[0]}} 
      comments: {{ item.value[1] }}
   loop: "{{ user |dict2items}}"
```

I'm not sure for value.
i think the ouput of user is { user:[ip_address,comments],...}
Look your's structure dictonnaries, i think my purpose is good but adapt it.

source https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-dictionary

Comment: for the loop, use

loop: "{{ user.dict |dict2items }} "

```
 - name: add-host
    check_point.mgmt.cp_mgmt_host:
      name: {{ item.value.Name }}
      ip_address: {{ item.value.IP} 
      comments: {{ item.value.Comments}}
   loop: "{{ user |dict2items}}"
```